# Does pgpool run on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, pgpool

Do you know if pgpool run with cygwin on windows ?
If it does, do know any tutorial ?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you just want to test pgpool. If you just want to test, you could utilize [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).